# Refer few Ids through the index action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

While we refer to all the datas in the model through index action in our controller as

for example

```
@task = Task.all
```

How to refer to the first three data's in the model database which we want to use. Like finding arrays like

```
@task =  Task.find(id: [1,2,3])
```

Is it possible to only get the three first data.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rails `first` method can take a parameter of how many you want

```
@task = Task.first(3)
```